# How to get div height of his parent while using d-flex in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

The problem is that I want the navigation menu to be 100% height of bordered div and I don't really know where is the issue.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class=" mt-5 border rounded h-100">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column navbar-dark bg-dark rounded-start float-start h-100">
    <div class=" flex-column px-2" style="">
      <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" d-flex flex-column content p-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel lacus a sem hendrerit lobortis. Vestibulum vel nulla non velit rhoncus eleifend. Suspendisse molestie nec nisl cursus fringilla. Morbi aliquet turpis sit amet pulvinar bibendum. Curabitur
    non nunc in tellus vehicula volutpat molestie malesuada ante. In lobortis quam sed maximus scelerisque. Duis imperdiet mollis ornare. Morbi aliquet turpis sit amet pulvinar bibendum. Curabitur
    non nunc in tellus vehicula volutpat molestie malesuada ante. In lobortis quam sed maximus scelerisque. Duis imperdiet mollis ornare.
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. You have to remove height(`h-100`) from `navbar-dark` and please give `d-flex` to the parent element.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/1j87zkqb/

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex  mt-5 border rounded h-100">
  <div class="d-flex flex-column navbar-dark bg-dark rounded-start float-start">
    <div class=" flex-column px-2" style="">
      <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="logout.php">Logout</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class=" d-flex flex-column content p-3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed vel lacus a sem hendrerit lobortis. Vestibulum vel nulla non velit rhoncus eleifend. Suspendisse molestie nec nisl cursus fringilla. Morbi aliquet turpis sit amet pulvinar bibendum. Curabitur
    non nunc in tellus vehicula volutpat molestie malesuada ante. In lobortis quam sed maximus scelerisque. Duis imperdiet mollis ornare. Morbi aliquet turpis sit amet pulvinar bibendum. Curabitur non nunc in tellus vehicula volutpat molestie malesuada
    ante. In lobortis quam sed maximus scelerisque. Duis imperdiet mollis ornare.
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-b5kHyXgcpbZJO/tY9Ul7kGkf1S0CWuKcCD38l8YkeH8z8QjE0GmW1gYU5S9FOnJ0" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Ye, that's what I was expecting, Thank you a lot. I've tried many combinations but didn't come up with this one :D